SSL wrong version number error when using get request from react app to a flask app
im trying to build a simple application using react to display my webpage while requesting data from a python server. Fetching data originally worked fine but recently I keep receiving a SSL wrong version number error when fetching data.
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2559)
For flask app:
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from readEmail import readEmail, testEmails, plainEmails



app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/plain/data', methods = ["GET"])
def getPlain():
    emails = plainEmails()
    return jsonify(emails)

for my webpage im using the function
const getData2 = () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/plain/data")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setEmailData(data)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("error fetching", error)
      setTimeout(getData2, 500)
    })
  }

I have tried updating urllib but the error still keeps occurring.

Based on what you write you are using plain HTTP and not HTTPS in your URL. An SSL error can only happen here if you have some redirect to HTTPS, which you don't show. Or it can happen if you have a proxy configured, but use the wrong URL (https instead of http) for the proxy.

Yes, so far I am just using plain HTTP, do not have any proxy configured. I have added the error message
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2559)
to my post. A few days ago I was able to fetch data but now the error keeps occurring. directly using curl to get the data works

You cannot get this error message if you only use plain HTTP. Thus somewhere is an attempt to use HTTPS involved, only you don't show it. I've mentioned to common ways where HTTPS unexpectedly is used in my last comment.
